# Nginx: Proxypass to a docker image that handles ssl connections and letsencrypt certificate renewal

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, docker

I found this docker solution for my email server https://mailcow.email/. This solution has a web panel and certbot in it. What I want to to is to proxypass **both** http and https connections into the nginx docker image that has anything setup for both http and https handling. In other words I want:

- The internal certbot to be able to renew the internal certificates
- If and https connection come to my server let the docker image handle it
- If an http request comes and is not for letsencrypt renewal force into https

So far what I've tried is to do this configuration:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name mail.example.com;
   #rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;

   location /.well-known/acme-challenge {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        client_max_body_size 100m;

   }

   location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8443/;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        client_max_body_size 100m;
   }
}
```

But without success. I can connect to https://example.com:8443 but not to https://example.com . But I managed to redirect into https when an http request gets received with the result of my browser unable to connect.

The docker image I wanna proxypass is:

```
2daeaa065165        nginx:mainline-alpine   "/bin/sh -c 'envsu..."   56 minutes ago      Up 56 minutes (healthy)   0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, 80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8443
```

And it listens for http connections into port 8080 and for https connections into port 8443.

Do you fellows have an Idea how I can fix this?

## Edit 1:

I changed the configuration into:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name mail.example.com;

   location /.well-known/acme-challenge {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        client_max_body_size 100m;

   }

   location / {
        rewrite ^(.*) https://$server_name$1 permanent;
   }

}

server {
 listen 443;
 server_name mail.example.com;

 ssl_certificate     /opt/docker-mailcow/data/assets/ssl/cert.pem;
 ssl_certificate_key /opt/docker-mailcow/data/assets/ssl/key.pem;
 ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
 ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;


 location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        client_max_body_size 100m;
 }

}
```

And the browser returns this message:

> An error occurred during a connection to mail.thundermail.ml. SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length. Error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG

Also the keys have these permissions:

```
pcmagas@DockerMailserver:/opt/docker-mailcow/data/assets/ssl$ ls -l
σύνολο 24
drwxr-xr-x 3 root    root    4096 Ιούν 23 20:35 acme
-rw-r--r-- 1 pcmagas pcmagas 1675 Ιούν 23 19:49 ca-key.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 pcmagas pcmagas 1034 Ιούν 23 19:49 ca.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 pcmagas pcmagas 1107 Ιούν 23 19:49 cert.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 pcmagas pcmagas  424 Ιούν 23 19:49 dhparams.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 pcmagas pcmagas 1679 Ιούν 23 19:49 key.pem
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the nginx configuration into:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name mail.example.com;

   location /.well-known {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/.well-known ;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        client_max_body_size 100m;

   }

   location / {
        rewrite ^(.*) https://$server_name$1 permanent;
   }

}

server {
 listen 443 ssl;
 server_name mail.example.com;

 ssl_certificate     /opt/docker-mailcow/data/assets/ssl/cert.pem;
 ssl_certificate_key /opt/docker-mailcow/data/assets/ssl/key.pem;
 ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
 ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;


 location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        client_max_body_size 100m;
 }

}
```

Where `ssl_certificate` and `ssl_certificate_key` points to a file that is a directory that `acme-mailcow` docker image volume generates the certificates.

Please keep in mind to set `ADDITIONAL_SAN` and `MAILCOW_HOSTNAME` the correct MX record of your mailserver.

Also replace the `mail.example.com` with your own MX record (that should be the same with A record in my case).